# ImportError raised when try to load crispy_forms

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

```
ImportError raised when trying to load  
‘crispy_forms.templatetags.crispy_forms_field’: No module named  
‘django.utils.lru_cache’
```

I get that error ^^ when i try to run the command below:

heroku run python manage.py migrate

I have checked that my crispy forms version = 1.8.1

Please help!

Comment: Have you followed below documentation.  https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Comment: @VaibhavMishra yeah, i have followed to documentation exactly so far

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken it's most likely because your version of Django might be outdated. According to [this issue from the official crispy-forms repo](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/issues/956) [(found here)](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=lru_cache+) you need `Django 3.0`

Try updating and see if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I uninstalled django 2 and installed django 3 and i am still getting the same error

Comment: @RitvikShah Are you running Django with `python manage.py runserver` or `python3 ...` ? because lru_cache is a decorator introduced from `3.x`